# Select all first children

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to select all the C's in B's for the following sample XML:

```
<A>
  <B>
     <C>want this</C>
     <C>don't want this</C>
  </B>
  <B>
     <C>want this, too</C>
     <C>still don't want this</C>
  </B>
<C>definitely don't want this, or any other c</C>
</A>
```

How is this possible? I tried `//B/C[1]` but it only returned the first element. In the sample XML, I put a C outside the B because the C's are really common elements that can exist elsewhere, also.

Edit: Would be nice if the xpath could be extended in such a way that I could also get the all the second children from B because I need that, also.

Comment: Try `//B/C[position()=1]`

Comment: @Andersson: That's no different than `//B/C[1]`.

Comment: @kjhughes, and both should work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath that you say you've tried,

```
//B/C[1]
```

is exactly what you want to select all first `C` elements of `B` elements:

```
<C>want this</C>
<C>want this, too</C>
```

without any of the other `C` elements.

If you're not seeing both `C` elements as shown above, then something is filtering to only the first result before you see it.  Perhaps you're passing to another function that automatically takes the first node of a nodeset.

Comment: Hm. Thanks for confirming my suspicion. If you're familiar with Appium at all, would you know why this doesn't work?

Comment: I've never used Appium, but be on the lookout for any intervening functions between `//B/C[1]` and your results that may return only the first node of a nodeset.  For example, in XPath 1.0, `string(//B/C[1])` returns only `"want this"`, not `"want thiswant this, too"`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out.